# Como chamar menu dentro de outro arquivo

Tags: php, html, funções, menu, header

Quero chamar um arquivo de menu feito em html, dentro de outro arquivo html para reutilizar o código sem que precise digitar tudo novamente para cada módulo do menu. Tenho que utilizar o PHP pra fazer isso? Segue código abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">

<title> Painel administrativo </title>

<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="C:/Desenvolvimento/Projeto_ChatBot/Version1.1/modulo_admin/images/favicon.png">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="C:/Desenvolvimento/Projeto_ChatBot/Version1.1/modulo_admin/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Menu CSS -->
<link href="C:/Desenvolvimento/Projeto_ChatBot/Version1.1/modulo_admin/bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Menu CSS -->
<link href="C:/Desenvolvimento/Projeto_ChatBot/Version1.1/modulo_admin/bower_components/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="C:/Desenvolvimento/Projeto_ChatBot/Version1.1/modulo_admin/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- JS and jQuery -->

<script src="C:/Desenvolvimento/Projeto_ChatBot/Version1.1/modulo_admin/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="C:/Desenvolvimento/Projeto_ChatBot/Version1.1/modulo_admin/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="C:/Desenvolvimento/Projeto_ChatBot/Version1.1/modulo_admin/bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
<!--Nice scroll JavaScript -->
<script src="C:/Desenvolvimento/Projeto_ChatBot/Version1.1/modulo_admin/js/jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>
<!--Morris JavaScript -->
<script src="C:/Desenvolvimento/Projeto_ChatBot/Version1.1/modulo_admin/bower_components/raphael/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="C:/Desenvolvimento/Projeto_ChatBot/Version1.1/modulo_admin/bower_components/morrisjs/morris.js"></script>
<!--Efeitos no menu -->
<script src="C:/Desenvolvimento/Projeto_ChatBot/Version1.1/modulo_admin/js/waves.js"></script>
<!-- Tema padrão do admin -->
<script src="C:/Desenvolvimento/Projeto_ChatBot/Version1.1/modulo_admin/js/myadmin.js"></script>
<script src="C:/Desenvolvimento/Projeto_ChatBot/Version1.1/modulo_admin/js/dashboard1.js"></script>
<script src="C:/Desenvolvimento/Projeto_ChatBot/Version1.1/modulo_login/controller/logoff.js"> </script>
```

Administração

SIR Steakhouse

```
        </nav>
        <div class="navbar-default sidebar nicescroll" role="navigation">
            <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse ">
                <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                    <li class="sidebar-search hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
                        <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="ti-search"></i> </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="dashboard.html" class="waves-effect"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire fa-fw"></i>
                        Dashboard</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="C:/Desenvolvimento/Projeto_ChatBot/Version1.1/modulo_admin/cad_option.html" class="waves-effect"><i class="ti-layout fa-fw"></i>Cadastros</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="waves-effect"><i class="ti-info fa-fw"></i>Informações</a>
                    </li>
                    <li> 
                        <a href="C:/Desenvolvimento/Projeto_ChatBot/Version1.1/modulo_login/views/login.html" onclick="return logoff();" class="waves-effect"><i class="ti-power-off fa-fw"></i>Sair</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                
                <div class="center p-20">

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
        </div>

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row bg-title">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h4 class="page-title"></h4> 
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">

                        </ol>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->



                <!-- row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <footer class="footer text-center"> 2021 &copy; Todos os direitos reservados <a
            href="dashboard.html">SIR Steakhouse</a> </footer>
        </div>   

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Opa, sim, com php seria uma boa, você pode criar meio q um "componente" reusável. Daí teria seu arquivo `menu.php` e incluiria ele aonde bem entendesse. Mas pra isso funcionar, não poderia ser em um arquivo `.html`

No seu arquivo pai e tals:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <?php require 'menu.php' ?>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Daí, se tu tiver html dentro do arquivo incluído, será reusado na tela =)